# mobile-ffmpeg: No such file or directory

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile-ffmpeg

I'm using mobile-ffmpeg to convert a .mp4 file to .mjpeg file so that it can be processed by opencv, the problem is it cannot find the file

this is my code:

```
 File video = new File(GlobalValue.uri.getPath());
            File dfanFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+"Dfan");
            if(!dfanFolder.exists()){
                dfanFolder.mkdir();
            }
            String videoPath = video.getAbsolutePath();
            String mjpegPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+"Dfan"+File.separator+"text.mjpeg";

            int rc = FFmpeg.execute("-i '" + videoPath + "' -vcodec mjpeg '" +mjpegPath+"'");

            VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
            videoCapture.open(mjpegPath);
```

and the error is

```
E/mobile-ffmpeg: /raw/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20210715_102314.mp4: No such file or directory
```